# Store the integrity of a table's records

Tags: database, database-normalization

I had a question that I couldn't solve/answer, to exemplify I'll give a use case. I have an ORDER_ITEMS table that is related to the ORDER table and a PRODUCT(ID, PRODUCT_NAME) table that is related to ORDER_ITENS. As the sales system is fed, I have a history of orders and their products sold, let's say I change the PRODUCT_NAME, all products sold prior to the change will have their name changed as a result of the reference between the ORDER_ITEMS table with PRODUCT. Is there a pattern where I could store the integrity of the PRODUCT_NAME without affecting the orders placed before the product name change?

Comment: What is "store the integrity of the PRODUCT_NAME" trying to say other than "store the PRODUCT_NAME"? What is stopping you from storing it? (Where are you stuck following what presentation of what design method?) PS Recording data as it was in an invoice is a multiple duplicate Q&A. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask] [Help]

Comment: add a effective date on the product table

Answer (score 0):

Such a join in a relational database looks up the current value.

If you need a history of that foreign field at the time of the child’s creation, make a copy. Add a column on the child table into which you copy the value of interest from the parent.

You likely will also want to capture the moment of this creation-and-copying by adding yet another column on the child table, of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

An alternative is to add an intermediate table, a child table to the parent with a pair of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`  columns that track when the sibling columns‘ values are in effect. Each time you modify the product’s name, you create a new row in this “in-effect” table. Each order item would link to a row in this “in-effect” table, with the more general product table being a grandparent to the order item.